# Saving an object list as JSON in UWP

Tags: c#, json

Can anyone tell me how to save an serialize an object array to json in UWP? I tried this way but it is not working well. The file is missing text after length. I'm Using Newtonsoft.Json;

Code -

```
private void btn_saveModel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SaveModel();

    }

    StorageFile file;

    private async Task openSaveFile()
    {
        var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        // Dropdown of file types the user can save the file as
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JSON", new List<string>() { ".json" });
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
        // Default file name if the user does not type one in or select a file to replace
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Data";

        StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

        this.file = file;
    }

    private void SaveModel()
    {
        var task = openSaveFile();
        Task.WhenAll(task);
        if (file != null)
        {
            var handle = file.CreateSafeFileHandle(options: FileOptions.RandomAccess);
            var stream = new FileStream(handle, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, LoadedIntents);

        }
    }
```

Input -

```
[
   {"tag": "greeting",
    "patterns": ["Hi", "Hey", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Hay"],
    "responces": ["Hello", "Hi", "Hi there"]
   },
   {"tag": "goodbye",
    "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye"],
    "responces": ["See you later", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again"]
   },
   {"tag": "thanks",
    "patterns": ["Thanks", "Thank you", "That's helpful", "Thanks for the help"],
    "responces": ["Happy to help!", "Any time!", "My pleasure", "You're most welcome!"]
   },
   {"tag": "about",
    "patterns": ["Who are you?", "What are you?", "Who you are?" ],
    "responces": ["I.m Osumen, your virtual friend", "I'm Osumen, a Friend who has an Artificial Intelligence"]
   },
   {"tag": "name",
   "patterns": ["what is your name", "what should I call you", "whats your name?"],
   "responces": ["You can call me Osumen.", "I'm Osumen!", "Just call me as Osumen"]
   },
   {"tag": "help",
   "patterns": ["Could you help me?", "give me a hand please", "Can you help?", "What can you do for me?", "I need a support", "I need a help", "support me please"],
   "responces": ["Tell me how can assist you", "Tell me your problem to assist you", "Yes Sure, How can I support you"]
   },
   {"tag": "complaint",
   "patterns": ["have a complaint", "I want to raise a complaint", "there is a complaint about a service"],
   "responces": ["Please provide us your complaint in order to assist you", "Please mention your complaint, we will reach you and sorry for any inconvenience caused"]
   }
```

]

After saving this even without a change, I get this

[
{
"Tag": "greetings",
"Patterns": [
"greetings",
"Hi",
"Hey",
"Is anyone there?",
"Hello",
"Hay"
],
"Responces": [
"Hello",
"Hi",
"Hi there"
]
},
{
"Tag": "goodbye",
"Patterns": [
"Bye",
"See you later",
"Goodbye"
],
"Responces": [
"See you later",
"Have a nice day",
"Bye! Come back again"
]
},
{
"Tag": "thanks",
"Patterns": [
"Thanks",
"Thank you",
"That's helpful",
"Thanks for the help"
],
"Responces": [
"Happy to help!",
"Any time!",
"My pleasure",
"You're most welcome!"
]
},
{
"Tag": "about",
"Patterns": [
"Who are you?",
"What are you?",
"Who you are?"
],
"Responces": [
"I.m Osumen, your virtual friend",
"I'm Osumen, a Friend who has an Artificial Intelligence"
]
},
{
"Tag": "name",
"Patterns": [
"what is your name",
"what should I call you",
"whats your name?"
],
"Responces": [
"You can call me Osumen.",
"I'm Osumen!",
"Just call me as Osumen"
]
},
{
"Tag": "help",
"Patterns": [
"Could you help me?",
"give me a hand please",
"Can you help?",
"What can you do for me?",
"I need a support",
"I need a help",
"support me please"
],
"Responces": [
"Tell me how can assist you","Tell me your problem to assi

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to await the `Task.WhenAll(task)`. You also didn't flush the StreamWriter. This is not really a UWP question; the problem is entirely in the code that is unrelated to UWP.

Comment: Thank you... 
I'm still new to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`Task.WhenAll(task);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0) you're using an asynchronous method that attempts to complete the `task` immediately, and if it DOESN'T it should continue executing code to work on other things while it works in the background.

However when you use the keyword [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) such as: `await Task.WhenAll(task);` something different happens.

The await keyword tells the compiler "you should try to complete this task immediately, if it doesn't finish it in time, continue working on it, **BUT** i will wait patiently for you to finish it."

Without `await`ing the `Task.WhenAll` if `openSaveFile` doesn't finish and return **immediately** `SaveModel` will continue to execute it's code instead of waiting patiently. Which is why sometimes you get half-baked results form the `SaveModel` becuase you're demanding the results before it has finished because you're not awaiting for the results.

You probably meant to use [`Task.WaitAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___System_TimeSpan_) which is the non-asynchronous version of `Task.WhenAll`, that forces waiting for the task to finish, no moving on without the results.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked after i added await and made the method async. also the length problem was corrected after flushing the stream writer.